# Where does "歩けど" come from?

Tags: grammar

The other day I came across this line in a game:

しかしそれ以外は誰とも出会わず、そして **歩けど歩けど** 代わり映えしない通路と部屋ばかり。

I guessed that 歩けど meant 歩いても from the context, but I had never seen a verb conjugated like that before. Is it something from a dialect, or perhaps classical Japanese?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The conjunctive particles [**ど**](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9) and [**ども**](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82) are Classical Japanese contradictory conjunctions, like the English *but* and *although*.  Although they aren't used as much anymore, you surely know them from the modern **けれど(も)**, and you probably know them from **いえども** and **されど** as well.

They attached to the 已然形 (realis stem), which in modern Japanese has been reanalyzed as the 仮定形 (hypothetical stem).  In this case, that stem is **歩け**, so you get **歩けど**.

Here, the **〜ど〜ど** pattern has the verb redoubled for emphasis:

> 歩け**ど**歩け**ど**

Since it's literary, we could try to give it a literary sounding translation:

> **歩けど歩けど**、岩しか見えなかった。
>   **Walk and walk as I might**, I could see only rocks.

Hopefully you can see the meaning from this simplified example.

Answer (score 4):

It comes from Classical Japanese but it is used in Modern Japanese much more often than you appear to think.

「ど」 is a contrastive, conjunctive particle. 　「[歩]{ある}けど」 means the same thing as 　「歩くけれども」 and 「歩くが、しかし」.

You speak of the conjugation but the ど is not part of the conjugation.  歩け　is the [已然形]{いぜんけい} of the verb 歩く.